# Can I send a generator through a REST service in Python?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, generator

We have been sending a huge Result Set(which is over a million rows) from our database to the client using a REST service. This causes the whole result set to be loaded up in memory, it packs the whole thing up and sends it over to the client. The client has to download this huge amount of data before any processing can be done. I am trying to figure out a way to stream data between a server and a client.

We already have the REST service, so I am trying to send over a a Python generator from the server side (database) to the client, and the client just has to deal with the current chunk of data, and when it is done with the current chunk it can just call next().

I am not sure if this works as intended, do any of you know if the generator on the server side generates the whole data and then sends it over? Or does this actually works?

I am also thinking of using Python sockets if the REST service does not work, but I am open to suggestions. If anybody has dealt with something like this before, what did you do?

I have to use Python for this by the way.

I have tried using generators and I get all the data, but I am not sure if it is actually being sent over in chunks or if it is being generated in whole on the server side and being sent over, which defeats the purpose of it.

This just psudo-code to show what I am doing

```py
#server
@app.route(/stream_data)
def stream_data():

    def gen()
        while data:
            yield data[:chunk_size]
        return
    return requests.response(gen())

#client
def main():
    url = 'blabla@rest.service.com'
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        for x in r.iter_content():
             print(x)
```

I am getting the data and everything works okay, but I am not sure if it actually streaming or just sending the whole thing over.

Comment: You can't sent a generator over HTTP. HTTP can only transport text. You may need to stream the data on both ends, or introduce pagination, or use sockets or something.

Comment: Pagination is the usual way to deal with this in a REST API. The simplest form is basically offset pagination. So, for example, you limit the maximum size they can query to 1000 records. First they query to see the number of records. Then if there are say, 10,000 records; they can query 1-1000, 1001-2000... and so on.